# Change User Location Blue Pulsing Circle Radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Is it possible to change the radius of the blue pulsing circle around current user's location in MapKit? I have an application which looks around current location for points of interest within a certain radius. I'd like to show this circle to the user without having to completely provide a new annotation for current user location. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This radius signifies the GPS's inaccuracy. I don't think you can override its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which is open source and allows you full access to this component. In MapKit, you can only change the tinted user dot, but not the circle.

Comment: Note that the MapBox developer is now charging for their new 2.0 version, but the legacy SDK is still available for free on GitHub: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy/blob/release/README-old.markdown