# Remove or edit user location blue pulsing circle

Tags: swift, mapkit, geometry

I'm trying to change the radius and color of the blushing blue circle that's created around a current user's location a MapKit? After searching for answers I found an old question [Change User Location Blue Pulsing Circle Radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658333/change-user-location-blue-pulsing-circle-radius) but the answer is an old objective-C service that costs money. Is there anything new in swift that would make this task easier, or is there a way to just remove the pulsing blue circle all together

Comment: The MapBox developer is charging for their new 2.0 version, but the legacy SDK is still available for free on GitHub: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy/blob/release/README-old.markdown

Comment: Also, Joe, your question sounds very useful. If you find a solution, consider posting an answer here too.

Answer (score 7):

The blue color for the user location is based on the tint color of your map view, changing this will set the new color for the user location circle.

```
//Objective-C 
mapView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

//Swift
mapView.tintColor = redColor()
```

If you wish to remove or replace the user location circle with something different you can change the didAnnotation delegate method.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *usrLoc = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
    usrLoc.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the radius since it represents the GPS accuracy.

Comment: Can you change the color, or at least remove it all together?

Answer (score -1):

In swift 4, 
I choosed a clear color so it is less anoying than a red or blue color to see below the map's details.

```
        mapView.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```